Can you get expelled for taking pictures on college campus?
I've heard that many colleges, including the one I attend, say that to film on campus requires a permit from the chancellor. However, I've seen thousands of people post pictures of themselves, their group of friends, events, and the scenery of campus, onto social media sites like Facebook & Instagram. Can they get in trouble for this? Is it against the rules to photograph on college property and post online?

I don't think this is answerable in general. It would depend  on the actual rules in place at the particular school, the particular punishment specified for violating them, and how strictly those rules are actually enforced by the administration in place at the time.

The tags you originally chose didn't seem to have anything to do with this question. Tags are important for helping your question find an interested audience. I've changed the tags; please choose them with more care when you post here in the future.

To me, "film on campus" means making an actual movie (say a documentary or similar) to be published officially (for money or impact) not just taking moving pictures for personal use. What is the actual wording you have in mind?

I think it is exceedingly unlikely that any university (at least in Europe/USA; perhaps other cultures would be different) will discipline a student for taking personal photos. Of course, action might be taken if the student's behaviour is disruptive, intrusive, harassing, etc - but this would be a response to the behaviour rather than to the photography.

I looked at what UC Berkeley web site says, for example. https://bcbp.berkeley.edu/brand-protection/request-permission/filmingphotography#commercial I think a monetizable Instagram would fall under "commercial".

It would probably also depend on the size and character of the expected audience. You probably could not do anything against some rando that photographs your house, but if this becomes a regular occurrence or grows exponentially, you would want to put a stop to it if you can. That being said, if the area in front of the house is public ground, you might have limited recourse, as politicians and film stars will know. Also, if you live in a culturally remarkable building, you might have copyright powers, but probably cannot prevent anything, unless the ground is your property.

One case is where I video a professor during class saying something controversial or outrageous, then post it on social media.  If it becomes a big controversy, then yes, I could be expelled.

I doubt that taking pictures of yourself, friends, and family will be considered improper. Or even taking a picture of the department offices where you spent a lot of time.
The issue is that for some, probably commercial, purposes, the university doesn't want the campus used as a backdrop for some narrative that might, if not vetted, reflect poorly on the university.
Another issue with such films that will be widely shared, published, and/or commercialized, is the possibility that people not involved in the film, but recognizable, will be caught on tape and their likeness uses without permission.
So, it is a matter of protecting the reputation of the place and the privacy of the people.
I also doubt that such rules would/could apply to news organizations filming when some unfortunate thing happens (shootings, bombing, ...). They might like to keep the news out, and might want someone along with the film crew for the reasons given above, but probably can't stop it - especially for a government funded university ("Public" in US terminology).

Ah, yes. Some sorts of pictures are improper and likely illegal. For that you could be expelled or even jailed.

The specific guidelines that limit what you can post and how you can post it will vary from institution to institution. They can include trademark or license limitations on the use of institutional icons or backdrops. Copyright guidelines provide a more general framework to define what you can and cannot post. They prohibit you from distributing content that you do not own by copyright. In a nutshell, a photographic reproduction of a work is itself in most cases considered a copy of the source, and only the person who owns the copyright has the right to determine how to distribute copies of the work the (hence the term copy-right). Therefore, while you can take photos of copyrighted content, you cannot post any of them.
One specific example is the Nittany Lion statue at Penn State University. Plenty of folks talk their pictures with it. No one is permitted to take a picture of it to use in marketing or promotional content without prior (written contractual) permission due to trademark limitations. Correspondingly, I imagine icon buildings at a university are wonderful backdrops for personal graduation pictures, yet those same backdrops may never be used in marketing or promotional distributions (again without prior written permission). Another example is a class lecture. You might be fine to take a picture of your class instructor without asking in advance (but you truly should ask in advance) and posting that picture to a friend in the class. You will walk the line for copyright infringement by taking a picture of the lecture notes from that same instructor and posting to a classmate because the instructor owns the copyright and you have no permission as such to distribute the content in any form.
So, when you post a picture of a campus setting on-line without the intent to obtain a market value or promotion but rather because you are displaying a personal picture that you have as a representation of some aspect or exchange in your personal life, no problem. Here is the Nittany Lion statue that I visited while at PSU last year. OK. Good. When you post that same content for marketing purposes -- Here is the Nittany Lion Statue to support my call to all PSU alumni to donate to my GoFundMe Page -- you likely have crossed a line on trademark or licensing limitations. When you post a celebration picture with you and your family at the iconic MIT central building, OK. When you post the same to promote your qualifications to a job (here is proof that I attended MIT), you may cross the line again on trademark issues. Finally, never post or otherwise distribute pictures that contain images of content that is copyrighted to someone else.
The consequences for violations of specific guidelines (trademark, license, or otherwise) are defined by the institution. The same may be true of copyright violations, whereby the copyright holder also always has their own recourse through the broader country-wide legal system.

Universities may impose conduct rules on their students, completely independent of intellectual property law. Violations wouldn't result in lawsuits, jail, fines, etc, but by internal discipline such as suspension or expulsion. So this question can't be answered on the basis of IP law, or any other law for that matter. (As I commented above, I don't think it can really be answered at all.)
